# Is there a security difference between storing files outside of the DocumentRoot versus "deny from all" htaccess directives?

Tags: security, .htaccess, document-root

Knowing that a `deny from all` directive will traverse all sub-directories and files below it, and ignoring the obvious caveats of "if you forget" to copy the `.htaccess` file or if you typo creating an `.htaccess` file...

Is there a risk in **security** between storing non-public files outside of the DocumentRoot *versus* placing an `.htaccess` file with a `deny from all` directive in each non-public directory *in* the DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to consider here:

1. .htaccess is only going to protect your file from access over the
   web. For example, suppose you have a typical FTP server setup with
   virtual users who are restricted to the document root. If an
   attacker gains access to your FTP server (which is not that
   far-fetched given how insecure most FTP configurations are), they
   will have access to both the .htaccess file and any of your
   protected files that are in the document root.

   That was just one example that may not apply to your environment,
   but the idea that I'm really trying to get at is that .htaccess
   files don't give you that much depth in your security. They protect
   you in one context (access over the Internet) but not in others.
2. Your server administrator has the ability to disable specific .htaccess 
   directives, to disable certain Apache modules (which your .htaccess file 
   may use), and even to disable the use of .htaccess files period. If you 
   don't have control over your Apache configuration (which I'm assuming 
   is the case since you're choosing to overwrite it with an .htaccess file), 
   you also don't really have control over whether your .htaccess file is going
   to be respected. It really comes down to your relationship with your
   host/server administrator and what they decide to allow.
3. Finally, if the .htaccess file is writable by the user your Apache
   server is running as, a determined hacker can modified that file.
   Ex. if you're using Wordpress, many popular themes will demand write
   access to the .htaccess file so that they can control URL rewriting.
   I'd imagine some other Content Management Systems do the same.

With all that said, using an .htaccess file (or directly altering your Apache configuration files) may still be a perfectly valid security measure for you. It depends on what your environment as a whole looks like -- how your server is configured, what you're trying to protect, etc. Hopefully I at least gave you some things to think about.